# get Jboss 7 to use custom top down WSDL definition of your choosing, without having CXF generate a wsdl

Tags: java, jboss, wsdl, cxf

we are moving a topdown (wsdl first) ws from jboss4 to jboss7 and are having some difficulties with CXF. I am noticing that the large wsdl file located in 
standalone\data\wsdl\x.ear\x.war\x.wsdl
is not generated off the supplied xsd set, it seems to be generating off the classes. For instance our definition from JBoss4 reads (obfuscated)

```
<element name="x">
<complexType>
<sequence>
<element minOccurs="0" name="x" type="x"/>
<choice>
<element name="x" type="x"/>
<element name="x" type="x"/>
<element name="x" type="x"/>
<element name="x" type="x"/>
<element name="x" type="x"/>
</choice>
</sequence>
</complexType>
</element>
```

and the one generated by CXF has all the coice element replaced with minoccurs = 0, totally invalid for our actual use.

```
<xs:element name="x">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="x" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="x" type="ns1:x"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="x" type="ns1:x"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="x" type="ns1:x"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="x" type="ns1:x"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="x" type="ns1:x"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

This is because wsconsume builds our java classes and annotates them well enough to be parsed by cxf, but not well enough to actually present the initial intent of the complexTypes, so after much looking, how do you get Jboss 7 to use the WSDL definition of your choosing, without having CXF generate a wsdl? We will not be using Spring to make this happen, so... Discuss!

Answer (score 0):

so setting the wsdlLocation in the @webservice annotation lead to the error described here

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cxf-users/200806.mbox/%3C1932ACF3-DCD2-4073-83DD-981FC0F68F53@apache.org%3E

so it turned way simpler after reading it

the directions there list two options:

1) Update the @WebService annotation on the FooDocumentImpl class to 
have the serviceName/portName attributes that match the values in the 
wsdl.

2) Update the  element in your config to add the 
qnames for the service name and portname.

the first is if you are not using Spring, so after explicitly bringing the @WebService annotation to:

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "main.package.InterfaceWS", serviceName = "InterfaceWSService", name = "InterfaceWS", targetNamespace = "http://Interface.namespace.main", wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/InterfaceWS.wsdl" ,portName="InterfaceWSPort")
```

to match the service description in the InterfaceWS.wsdl:

```
<service name="InterfaceWSService">
                    <port binding="tns:InterfaceWSSOAPBinding" name="InterfaceWSPort">
                              <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/publishedLocationOfInterface />
                    </port>
</service>
```

it worked like a charm